# How can I remove a fraction p of nodes (or edges) from a graph randomly?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose we have the network (G) below : If we knock off each vertex with probability p .What fraction of G survive the attack? now if we knock off each edge with probability p.What fraction of (G) survive the attack?

G=[image]

PS: you can illustrate your suggestion with any random graph.

Ref: Réka Albert, Hawoong Jeong & Albert-László Barabási http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v406/n6794/full/406378a0.html

Comment: Neither.  Use built-in functionality.  Key functions: `RandomSample` for choosing vertices/edges to keep, `Subgraph` for removing what's not kept.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thank you for the reply. May I ask you please.. are you the same Szabolcs who created iGraph/M ? or is that just a coincidance? In both cases do you mind please kindly getting me started and put  me on track ?  any guidance would be greatly apreciated .

Comment: Yes.  IGraph/M simply makes some (not all) [igraph](http://igraph.org/) functionality easily usable from Mathematica.  It doesn't provide a new graph datatype, instead it integrates with the builtin `Graph`.  igraph is not my work, I only made a partial interface to Mathematica because I needed it.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Respect. That stuff is very impressive and fairly documented. Im not a born to be programmer but I am trying to wrap my hear around it. Any suggestions to how to begin tackling this problem ? your generosity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Combinatorica is a very old package from the time when Mathematica couldn't do graphs on its own.  To use it, it is essential to get [the book](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/).  It is focused on mathematics and graph theory.  It is too slow for working with large graphs and stuff that people call "network science". Reading the book will be most useful if you want to learn some graph theory (math) and in particular graph algorithms or algorithms for dealing with groups (abstract algebra).

Comment: @Szabolcs.  I did read that book , now I am trying to learn to get some "savoir-faire" through iGraph/M.

Comment: I think that should be a separate and concisely phrased question.  Example: "How can I remove a fraction $p$ of nodes (or edges) from a graph randomly?".  Phrasing the questions this way will give you better answers.  Try not to mix too many things in the same post.  A starting point would be `VertexDelete[g, RandomSample[VertexList[g], Round[p VertexCount[g]]]]`.

Comment: @Scabolcs.Understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Szabolcs. The code did not go through . Where am i going the wrong way ? RandomSample::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 2 in RandomSample[{51,65,78,89,6.....<<75>>},Round[125 p]]   VertexDelete::inv: The argument RandomSample[{51,...., 259, <<75>>}, Round[125 p]]] is not a valid vertex.

Comment: Did you set a value for `p`?  `p = 0.1`.

Comment: @Szabolcs. I just did . Varying  p gives different soup pf subgraphs. In this case how can i for example run an n montecarlo and  average n/2 of p values for example? is that feasible ? is that even make sense? please be be patient with my very limited mind and naive questions.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Would any of your cliques function page 34 of IGraph/M Documentation PDF  be of  any help to my case here ? and if yes/ most importantly how can it be utilized here. Of course I am dealing with unweighted graphs ( i guess as I am not sure how MM does this at a deeper level).

Comment: @Szablocs. For some reason, I can't gt IGraph/M to run. <<IGraphM`
During evaluation of In[18]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open IGraphM`.
Out[18]= $Failed{\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"Message", "[", 
RowBox[{
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"Get", "::", "noopen"}], "MessageName"], ",", 
TagBox["\<\"IGraphM`\"\>",
HoldForm]}], "]"}],
HoldForm]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"<<", "\<\"IGraphM`\"\>"}],
HoldForm]\)}   Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like it's either not installed, or not installed in the correct location. Did you follow the instructions in the very first paragraph [here](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: @Szabolcs The iGraph/M work is I m sure quite good, but maybe you could post some simple Mathematica code as a response to the specific question? (I'm not against demoing third party packages, especially good ones. But when the original  poster claims to have trouble just getting started with coding, adding yet another install and set of language primitives to the mix seems like it could make for trouble.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Actually my very first comment was not to use any packages, and the code I showed in my comment is pure Mathematica.  OK, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I see now that the question was edited.  Please take a look at the original question to see why the packages are mentioned in the comments. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/130525/1

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the link, indeed I had not seen that. I will say that I much prefer the revised question, since it can be addressed (as you did) with straightforward code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To randomly remove a fraction $p$ of vertices or edges from a graph `g`, you can do the following:

```
p = 0.1; (* make sure p has a value *)

verticesToRemove = RandomSample[VertexList[g], Round[p VertexCount[g]]]

result = VertexDelete[g, verticesToRemove]
```

For edges:

```
edgesToRemove = RandomSample[EdgeList[g], Round[p EdgeCount[g]]]

result = EdgeDelete[g, edgesToRemove]
```

Is the result still connected?  Check it with [`ConnectedGraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedGraphQ.html).

If the result graph is not connected, you can look at what is the size of the largest component in the result, relative to the total graph size:

```
Length@First@ConnectedComponents[result]/VertexCount[result]
```

Try it on a scale free network created using preferential attachment:

```
g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[300, 2]]
```

Repeat the calculation 100 times and compute the average fraction of the largest component:

```
Table[
 verticesToRemove = RandomSample[VertexList[g], Round[p VertexCount[g]]];
 result = VertexDelete[g, verticesToRemove];
 Length@First@ConnectedComponents[result]/VertexCount[result],
 {100}
]

N@Mean[%]
```

Comment: Thx (and I was first to upvote even).

Comment: @Szabolcs.As you figured it out I used the master file  and did not see your comment/link/instructions. Got it to work now and love it!. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Szabolcs. I have a naive question .The  p=0.1 was just a random example right ? Can we integrate the p as a variable in the code like p= Range[0,1,0.1] ?

Comment: Yes, the starting point is `Table[..., {p, 0, 1, 0.1}]`